# batch convert DTS to Ac3

Tags: video, ffmpeg, batch

I'm looking for a way to run a script file in folder that contains mkv files and copy the video and subtitles and everything else as it is except the audio, convert it to AC3, and saving the new files in the same name using ffmpeg.

I found below script but it's not working.

```
FOR %%f IN (*.mkv) DO C:\Users\ConvertDTStoAC3\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i %1 -map 0 -vcodec copy -scodec copy -acodec ac3 -b:a 640k “%~d1%~p1%~n1”-AC3.mkv
```

Can you please help with that?

Answer (score 0):

In batch files %1 to %9 will expand to the first to ninth command line argument. But in For meta variable %%f, you have to use %%f instead of %1:

```
FOR %%f IN (*.mkv) DO C:\Users\ConvertDTStoAC3\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i %%f -map 0 -vcodec copy -scodec copy -acodec ac3 -b:a 640k “%%~dpnf-AC3.mkv"
```

If you are running this from cmd instead of a batch file, then replace %% with %.

Comment: thank you for reply. I've tried to run it from cmd and as a batch but both of them didn't work, it just popup and close immediately. what's the issue here ?